# Fuzzer in go replicating Python one

Tags: go

I'm recreating a fuzzer(the actual fuzzer is on the link and it's written in python) for this tutorial:

[Link for the tutorial](http://www.primalsecurity.net/0x0-exploit-tutorial-buffer-overflow-vanilla-eip-overwrite-2/)

> well actually the objective is to do all of the code but using Go.

**My question is more in terms of a correct way to do things the process to reach big incremental numbers in the code are getting slower and slower. Anyone have any ideia if there of a interface/lib that does this. Or any functionality that i´m forgeting in Go that could be use to do it better.:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

const payload = "\x41"

func main() {
    //Banner
    fmt.Printf("\nLauching Fuzzer..\n")
    payL := strings.Repeat(payload, 50)

    for {
        payL += strings.Repeat(payload, 50)
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:21")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Crash Error: ", err)
        }
        final_payload := fmt.Sprint("User " + payL + "\r\n")
        _, err = conn.Write([]byte(final_payload))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
            break
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Sending buffer with length: ", final_payload)
            conn.Close()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does the code you posted work? If not, what's the error message. If so, what's your question?

Comment: Hi @AdamSmith did you see the bold letters ?
But yes the code work, I got no error message(implicit when I said the code works), the question is in terms of efficiency ... what i'm looking is to see if anyone can replicate the same thing I did but in a more efficient way then I did . I know that my code could improve well just look at it :) if you see something that you would do different that would make it faster, or better in memory management wise .. well i'm open to suggestions or critics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for review, which is too broad on Stack Overflow. Consider asking your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead, but be sure to read their [asking guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first; specifically, add background & an desired output of your application to the question itself.

Comment: @Matt the problem is now described, and you got a example of what i´m doing, it´s not a code review or a request for reccommendations in libraries what i want to know if there is a function or a design solution that i did not implemented that could be implemented that could result in a speed increase in terms of processing the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [package fuzz](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gofuzz)
>
> ```
> import "github.com/google/gofuzz"
> ```
>
> Package fuzz is a library for populating go objects with random
>   values.

For an example of an efficient Go fuzzer, see the Go package fuzz.

Comment: thanks going to look at it